# getting wrong output with algorithm which is like Karatsuba

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, multiplication

I made a program to multiply two strings and I expected `1000*10 = 10000`, but I am getting `100000`. I don't know where my logic is wrong. I also tried replacing `m2` with `m1` in the expression  `((val3+val4) * 10**(m2))` but nothing works, and when I try to multiply `120 * 10`, I get `300`.

```
def Multiply_Recursive(a, b):
    if len(a) == 1 or len(b) == 1:
        return str(int(a)*int(b))
    else:
        m = max(len(a),len(b))
        m2 = m // 2
        m1 = len(b) // 2
        A = int(a[0:m2])
        B = int(a[m2:len(a)])
        C = int(b[0:m1])
        D = int(b[m1:len(b)])
        val1 = int(Multiply_Recursive(str(A),str(C)))
        val2 = int(Multiply_Recursive(str(B),str(D)))
        val3 = int(Multiply_Recursive(str(A),str(D)))
        val4 = int(Multiply_Recursive(str(B),str(C)))
        return str(val1 * 10**(2*m2) + ((val3+val4) * 10**(m2)) + val2)
num = Multiply_Recursive("1000","10")
print(num)
```

Comment: Have you added breakpoints to check the values of `val1, val2, val3, val4`?

Comment: not yet but checking right now

Comment: `m1` and `m2` aren't right .. in particular `m2` can be longer than `len(a)`. And then you need to correctly figure out the right powers of 10 to multiply the parts by in the return statement. For example, `val1` needs to be multiplied by `10**(len(a)-m2 + len(b)-m1)` I think.

Comment: You also have some needless conversions between str and int. `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` are all converted to int, only to convert them back to `str` when they're used.

Comment: @PaulHankin this value 10**(len(a)-m2 + len(b)-m1) not working

Comment: You also need to figure out the right powers of 10 for val3 and val4 for the code to work.

Comment: `a = A * 10**len(str(B)) + B` and `b = B * 10**len(str(C)) + C`. From this you can work out the right powers of 10, but at some point you need to debug your code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the final formula you assume that `m2` digits occur **at the right of** the split point, and that this number of digits is the same for both splits. Neither is generally true.

Also, as the definition of `m` depends on the larger input, it could lead to an out-of-range number of digits represented by `m2`, when `a` is *much* smaller than `b`.

You could fix this like this:

- Define `m2` like this:

  ```
    m2 = len(a) // 2
  ```
- Split the input in such a way that `m1` and `m2` are the number of digits *after* the split point, not before. So split like this:

  ```
    A = int(a[:-m2])
    B = int(a[-m2:])
    C = int(b[:-m1])
    D = int(b[-m1:])
  ```
- Change the final formula taking into account that `m1` and `m2` can be different. So for instance there should not be `2*m2`, but `m1+m2`, ...Etc:

  ```
    return str(val1 * 10**(m1+m2) + val3 * 10**m2 + val4 * 10**m1 + val2)
  ```

The real Karatsuba algorithm will make sure to choose `m1` and `m2` so they are the same, and it will not convert strings to integer unless it is certain the size of the strings is limited. It also needs one less recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

The naming is not helpful - just using ah, al, bh, bl:

```
def multiply_recursive(a, b):
    """ Return the product of a and b.

        All numbers are passed as their decimal string representations.
    """
    if not a or not b:
        return "0"
    if len(a) == 1 or len(b) == 1:
        return str(int(a)*int(b))
    #
    m = max(len(a), len(b))
    m2 = m // 2
    # different split points not suitable for common scaling of "mixed products" below
    # m1 = len(b) // 2
    # low parts are remainders: split from least significant end!
    ah, al = a[0:-m2], a[-m2:].lstrip("0")
    bh, bl = b[0:-m2], b[-m2:].lstrip("0")
    # print(ah, al, bh, bl, sep=',')
    ahbh = int(multiply_recursive(ah, bh))
    albl = int(multiply_recursive(al, bl))
    ahbl = int(multiply_recursive(ah, bl))
    albh = int(multiply_recursive(al, bh))
    product = str(ahbh * 100**m2 + (ahbl+albh) * 10**m2 + albl)
    # print(product)
    return product

num = multiply_recursive("1000","10")
print(num)
```

Comment: what is logic behind if not a or not b:
        return "0"

Comment: `.lstrip("0")` may result in an empty string (of length 0).

Comment: This program work right but this does not work for real karatsuba algorithm for three values in expression

Comment: `this does not work for the real Karatsuba algorithm for three values in expression` If you want another question answered, 1) search for an answer to it 2) ask that question.

Comment: i asked that question right now